# How to set Input type text value in html with css

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, azure-ad-b2c

The application doesn't support JavaScript, it only support HTML and CSS.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization

For security reasons, we don't allow you to include any JavaScript in your content. Most of what you need should be available out of the box. If not, use User Voice to request new functionality.

Text box is coming from azure , I don't have control over it.

I need to set the value of

```
 <input type="text" value="XXXXX"/>
```

How to do this using CSS ?

Comment: what application are you using that doesn't support js? That's IE6 stuff there xD

Comment: There is no way you can do that... except maybe if you have a parent element and setting your input background to transparent

Comment: In the meantime, JavaScript can be used in custom policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do that. You should use latest browser or something else to do this using JS.

Answer (score 2):

If you have your page running with PHP or another language (like ASP), you could render a value like

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo 'your value'; ?>">
```

So you won't need JS.

But using CSS to set the value is impossible.

**//edit**
Your last edit of your question stated, that you are not able to change your input field with Azure. So I guess you need to allow JS then. There is no other way I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

you should set type at the time of making either it's button type or text field if it's text field then you should asign it's type 
here is the example

```
<input value="text">
```

or

```
<input type ="text" value="your Text">
```

type might be text, tel, Date, number, email

Answer (score 0):

The HTML content supplied by Azure AD B2C contains an input field for logonIdentifier and an input field for the password field.

You can control the value of the logonIdentifier by passing the "login_hint" identifier in the URI.  For example replace [yourteannt],[yourpolicy],[yourclientid] in the URI below.  You should see "myemail@domain.com" pre-populated in the logonIdentifier field.

https://login.microsoftonline.com/[yourtenant].onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1_[yourpoicy]&client_id=[yourclientid]&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fjwt.ms&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login&login_hint=myemail@domain.com